# draw9patch showing the border in the emulator

Tags: java, android, chat

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the black borders are appearing in the emulator, and how to remove them?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your ninepatch image? maybe there is something wrong with it.

Comment: @Jave thanks for your quick response, I updated my question take look at it please !

Comment: Did you name the images correctly? ie image.9.png?

Comment: @ByteMe yes in drawable folder but in the code just the name like gray_bubble

Comment: that should still work. do you have another drawable named gray_bubble that isn't draw9?

Comment: @ByteMe thanks so much it works now, now I accepted the answer so I'm not lier and I didn't forget who told me a right solution =) 
thanks for your care and note ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add black lines along the upper edge and the left edge, it could be that the device does not accept it as a valid nine-patch if you are missing black on any of the sides.

This could be related to ninepatches that have 'gaps' in the black lines appear to work in the editor, but will not work on a device.

Edit:
And as @ByteMe states in a comment, make sure you have the `.9.png` at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem it was because I forgot to rename the images!! This shouldn't be an issue if you use the tools provided by Google to make draw9... but it'w worth double checking!

image should be named ***.9.png